# Collision detection with JavaScript and HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d, collision

I have a problem with collision detection in my 2D game. The collision is good at top and left of the object but doesn't work as expected at bottom and right of the object. How can I fix it? 
**Javascript:**

```
this.isPlayerCollideWith = function(object) {

    if (this.posX < objekt.posX + object.width && this.posX + this.width  > object.posX &&
        this.posY < object.posY + object.height && this.posY + this.height > object.posY) {

        //up
        if(this.posY < objekt.posY + object.height){
            this.posY -= this.speed;
        }
        //down
        if(this.posY + this.height > object.posY){
            this.posY += this.speed;
        }

        //left
        if(this.posX < object.posX + object.width){
            this.posX -= this.speed;
        }

        //right
        if(this.posX + this.width > object.posX){
            this.posX += this.speed;
        }

    }
};
```

All of my code is running through an HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `objekt` should be `object`.

You're collision logic might be (might not be) off also. Here's working code:

```
if(!(
    this.x             > object.x+object.width  ||
    this.x+this.width  < object.x           ||
    this.y             > object.y+object.height ||
    this.y+this.height < object.y
)){ ... }
```